# For single-producer, single-consumer should I use a BlockingCollection or a ConcurrentQueue?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, .net-4.0

For single-producer, single-consumer should I use a BlockingCollection or a ConcurrentQueue?

Concerns:

- My goal is to pull up to 100 items at a time and send them as a batch to the next step.
- If I use a ConcurrentQueue, I have to manually cause it to go asleep when there is no work to be done. Otherwise I waste CPU cycles on spinning.
- If I use a BlockingQueue and I only have 99 work items, it could indefinitely block until there the 100th item arrives.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx

Comment: It is a single-producer, single-consumer scenario. Or in other words, one thread is writing to the queue and one is reading from the queue.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably get away with using either. Though like you said if using the `ConcurrentQueue` then you would have to perform a spin wait while the queue was empty. That might not be so bad if you expect the lag between the producer and consumer to be short. In the end, I think you will find the `BlockingCollection` a lot more pliable for your scenario. It is the data structure of choice for the producer-consumer pattern afterall. There are a couple of different ways you could work around the indefinite wait problem.

- Use a sentinel value as a stopping indicator in the consumer. A `null` value inserted into the queue would work well here.
- Take advantage of the `CancellationToken` mechanism to unblock the `Take` method.

Answer (score -4):

You can use [java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/SynchronousQueue.html)

Comment: Seems like he is not using Java.